# Handling POST Requests in Java Http server

Tags: java, http, post, request, handle

I'm trying to handle a simple base64 string in my HTTP server by sending a POST request from postman with the String i need.

When I debug my server, i can see the request coming in, but the parameter is not transmitted.

I found this piece of code to handle POST request, but even though i see the request coming in, I cannot retrieve the value.

Any help would be appreciated, this is what I got now, and the response is empty:

```
public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {



        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(t.getRequestBody(), "utf-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String query = br.readLine();
        parseQuery(query, parameters);

        // send response
        String response = "lol";
        for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {
            response += key + " = " + parameters.get(key) + "\n ";
        }
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.toString().getBytes());
        os.close();

public static void parseQuery(String query, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    if (query != null) {
        String pairs[] = query.split("[&]");
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            String param[] = pair.split("[=]");
            String key = null;
            String value = null;
            if (param.length > 0) {
                key = URLDecoder.decode(param[0],
                        System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
            }

            if (param.length > 1) {
                value = URLDecoder.decode(param[1],
                        System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
            }

            if (parameters.containsKey(key)) {
                Object obj = parameters.get(key);
                if (obj instanceof List<?>) {
                    List<String> values = (List<String>) obj;
                    values.add(value);

                } else if (obj instanceof String) {
                    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                    values.add((String) obj);
                    values.add(value);
                    parameters.put(key, values);
                }
            } else {
                parameters.put(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling any web  service over here ?

Comment: My webservice is running on localhost:8000/test. I get the POST request response in Postman, but I can't retrieve any parameters

Comment: I'm sorry I'm mistaken. Actually, what I am running is a Java HTTP server with context /test connected to the Handler mentioned in my original post. How can I enable CORS in this specific simple http server to see if that is the problem?